# A Hidato, but with no given numbers?

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, no-computers

I can be a bit evil sometimes. Today, I am going to give you a Hidato with no numbers! It gets worse: This puzzle is on a Mobius Strip Y<sup>[1]</sup> However, I will give hints as to what the numbers are, so this isn't going to be plain impossible. Also, to make this a bit easier, this is only a 3x3 Hidato. Here is the puzzle:

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | C |
| D | E | F |
| G | H | I |

Hints:

> 1. $B,C,G,E$ are primes
> 2. $A,H,I$ are square numbers
> 3. $C$ does not connect with $I$
> 4. $A+1\lt C\lt H\lt G\lt E$
> 5. $A$ does not connect with $D$
> 6. There is only 1 connection that is made using a diagonal

The goal of Hidato is to fill the grid with a series of consecutive numbers adjacent to each other orthogonally or diagonally. The entire grid is required to be filled in.

<sup>[1]</sup>Here's an example. Say we are on an 8x8 grid at R1C1. If we walk up, we go to R8C1. However, this is not a torus, so going straight from R1C1 to R8C8 is illegal, however, since this is Hidato, we can do $R1C1\to R\color{red}2C8$ due to our ability to move diagonally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off,

> The four primes must be 2, 3, 5, 7 and the 3 squares must be 1, 4, 9.
>
>  A + 1 is at least 2 (since A can't be less than 1)
>  from (4), C, G, and E are all primes that are greater than 2 (A + 1 is at least 2)
>  thus C, G, and E are 3, 5, and 7 in that order, and that leave B as 2.
>
> ```
>  -------------
>  |   | 2 | 3 |
>  -------------
>  |   | 7 |   |
>  -------------
>  | 5 |   |   |
>  -------------
> ```

Next,

> The two numbers that are neither prime nor square are 6 and 8, and those must correspond to D and F (in some order).
>   If F is 6, we have a diagonal connection between 5 and 6, and there is no way to complete the grid without another diagonal, so F must be 8, and D is 6.
>
> ```
>  -------------
>  |   | 2 | 3 |
>  -------------
>  | 6 | 7 | 8 |
>  -------------
>  | 5 |   |   |
>  -------------
> ```

Finally,

> It doesn't take too much  more figuring to place the 3 square numbers.
>  C is greater than A + 1, so A is obviously 1.
>  C and I aren't connected, so the only other place 4 can go is at H.
>  That leaves I for 9.
>
> ```
>  -------------
>  | 1 | 2 | 3 |
>  -------------
>  | 6 | 7 | 8 |
>  -------------
>  | 5 | 4 | 9 |
>  -------------
> ```